# Highcharts export : button is missing when website on IIS server

Tags: asp.net, highcharts, export, iis-7.5

I have a problem using the export feature of Highcharts.
I develop under Visual Studio, using ASP.NET.
I'm using Highcharts V3, referencing the following files :

- highcharts.js
- highcharts-more.js
- exporting.js

When I test my web project launching it from Visual Studio (local server), everything works perfectly fine.

I then upload my website to the server (IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 server).
When I open the website from its URL there, the export context buttons simply do not display at the right top corner the charts. No errors, just no buttons defined in the  canvas of the charts.

Could someone please help me ?

Thanks you.

Comment: Do you receive any errors? Because it seems that exporting.js is not loaded

Comment: No error, it only act as if exporting.js is not loaded. But the code is the same on both my dev environnement and the server, hence my supposition it's a IIS issue...

Comment: So please check path to exporting.js which need to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into Similar issue using DotNet.HighChart Lib for Asp.net MVC.
While i was working on VS2012 and IIS Express everything was fine, but when i deployed it into local IIS on my PC or on an external Server running IIS 7 nothing of chart was shown (just a blank page), i checked the source code, it seemed that scripts where generated, but one of two js files [Highcharts, Exporting] was not included, it's an issue with Bundle, it has a different behaviour on server and I don't get it, All i did to solve my issue was ignoring Bundle and include js files directly.

I converted:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/highcharts")
```

to

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/highcharts/highcharts.exporting-1.0.0.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/highcharts/highcharts.min-1.0.0.js")
```

and it worked.

Just for extra info my Bundle was defined like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/highcharts").Include(
    "~/Scripts/highcharts/highcharts.exporting-1.0.0.js",
    "~/Scripts/highcharts/highcharts.min-1.0.0.js"
));
```

EDIT: I think i got what happened for me. Highcharts.js is not standalone, i mean it uses other js files that are physically located beside it. Bundles have different urls on development time and Deploy time. For ease of development it generated PHYSICAL urls and physical inner links of js files work then. But on server all bundles are mapped to a VIRTUAL path that are not related to their physical locations, so it causes that relative physical paths in those files are misaddressed on server and you get a 404 exception.

Hope it could be helpful

Comment: You'll have same issue with TinyMCE for exactly the same reason;) [if you ever use it]